# Webservice contract first reversed - refer Java class in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

We have a bunch of web services that are designed *contract first*. In the various WSDL files are included common XML fragments from the same XML schema definition. However, the result is that the same class like `Address` is created a couple of times for various webservices (wsimport).

Is it possible to go with *contract first*, yet first define a bunch or handful of Java classes that are referred in various WSDL files?
This would make programming easier on both front end and back end.

Comment: We are using jaxws-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching to cxf-codegen-plugin. It allows for more customization of code generation process.

With cxf-codegen-plugin you can map types namespaces to concrete package. Just specify common package for your shared classes:

```
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/service1/Service1.wsdl</wsdl>
    <extraargs>
        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
        <extraarg>http://yournamespace.com/types=com.namespace.types</extraarg>
        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
        <extraarg>http://yournamespace.com/service1=com.namespace.service1</extraarg>
    </extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/service2/Service2.wsdl</wsdl>
    <extraargs>
        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
        <extraarg>http://yournamespace.com/types=com.namespace.types</extraarg>
        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
        <extraarg>http://yournamespace.com/service2=com.namespace.service2</extraarg>
    </extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I also think that cxf-codegen-plugin may be the better solution. However, jaxws-maven-plugin also features mapping xml namespace to Java package of produced Java classes.
The problem still abides, how to use existing Java classes as "incoming items" to the webservice contract.